# Unique Constraint in SQL with Multiple NULL Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint

I recently read about a way to ensure unique values in a column in SQL while allowing multiple NULLS. 
This was done using filtered indexes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indexName ON tableName(columns) INCLUDE includeColumns 
WHERE columnName IS NOT NULL
```

Could someone explains how this actually works?
 Is the UNIQUE constraint created on the column or not ?

Comment: This will depend on the **concrete RDBMS** you're using - tag your question with `mysql`, `postgresql`, `oracle`,  `sql-server` , `db2` or whatever else you might be using !

Comment: I am using SQL Server...tagged

Comment: Unique refers the index not the table, so it works because the rows with NULL values aren't in the index.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: When the index is filtered, anything that doesn't fit the criteria in the where clause is simply left out of the index.
If the index is unique, the uniqueness is enforced only on the data that fits the criteria in the where clause.

To answer your second question: In Sql server unique constraints are implemented by creating unique indexes under the hood, so there really is not much difference between them. In any case the uniqueness is enforced on an index and not directly on the table column.